# Error CS0115 ,CS1061 with Uno + Prism + Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, uno-platform

I have a problem, since I have been trying to do what they say in the blog that talks about uwp and a platform in:

https://platform.uno/blog/uwp-winui-and-uno-platform-get-prism-support-thanks-to-uno-team-oss-contribution/

and errors come out everywhere.

Error CS1061 'App' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no accessible extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error CS0115 'App.CreateShell ()': no suitable method found to override

Error CS0117 'object' does not contain a definition for 'OnLaunched'

Error CS1061 'Shell' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no accessible extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'Shell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

of this type of errors, I get 18 more !!!

On the other hand, in the .Xaml, I also get several errors;

I can't add an Entry as it says "does not support direct content"

I can't add a Button as it says "does not support direct content"

I don't know how I should continue. Can you help me please?

I have the example on the GitHub and it is as follows https://github.com/ivanxamarin032019/Login_Prism_Uno.git

I am working with:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.5.1

I have updated the Nugets that have been insaved, except the two that put Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.xxx

Comment: I'm not sure if your repo is private or not but it just shows a 404

Comment: @IvanXam now that your repo is public, we can take a look. Have you been able to build the application, or is it only errors in the IDE ?

Comment: This looks like the nuget restore did not work at all, as I'm able to build your solution fine on my end. When you right click on the solution, the "restore nuget packages", what do you see ?

Comment: This is the message that appears to me, when I press that option.

But have you compiled it well? I don't get it, I have almost all the App.xaml.cs code with the red line since it doesn't recognize this.InitializeComponent, OnLaunched, OnSuspending, CreateShell, etc.

Comment: All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.6978876
========== Finished ==========

Comment: Yes the compilation works fine. What may happen here is that the prism packages did not restore properly. Which version have you updated to ?

Comment: My apologies, which version of the Prism nuget package have you updated to ?

Comment: Prism version 8.0.0.1717-ci